# Forge not working when i hit run in eclipse

Tags: java, minecraft-forge

I'm using forge version 1.16.5-36.1.24
and when I run the game it always gives this error. It worked before I reinstalled windows on my PC. I also use java JDK 1.8.0_301

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class cpw.mods.modlauncher.SecureJarHandler (in unnamed module @0x69379752) cannot access class sun.security.util.ManifestEntryVerifier (in module java.base) because module java.base does not export sun.security.util to unnamed module @0x69379752
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I figured it out. I need to go to Window > Preferences > Java > Installed JREs > and select Java JDK 1.8.0_301